Logic App SFTP-SSH trigger condition failing
I am trying to read files from SFTP using logic app SFTP-SSH connector. SFTP has multiple files, but we want to read files with file names starting with "Client" eg Client_xyz.txt, Client_123.txt.
I have added the trigger condition but SFTP trigger is continuously failing with error :
Expression :
@contains(base64ToString(triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['x-ms-file-name-encoded']),'Client')
OR
@contains(base64ToString(triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['x-ms-file-name']),'Client')
Code
InvalidTemplate
I can see this in the trigger output :
enter image description here
I check the expression using compose shape and expression is executing successfully and giving the desired result.
Please guide me if I am doing anything wrong here.
Thanks in advance.
Checked the expression in variable & compose shape and expression is giving the expected result.

I believe, you are using either Get file content or Get file content using path action to read the files but these actions expects either file id or path of the file as an input but you are passing contains(base64ToString(triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['x-ms-file-name']),'Client') expressions doesn't evaluates to the inputs expected by these actions.
Alternatively, I am using given workflow to read the file names starts with Client.



Able to get the contents.

Use given design while using When a file is added or modified trigger.



Ikhtesam Afrin : Apologies, Forgot to mention that I am using "When a file is added or modified" trigger to read the files.

@RaviRanjan Added an alternate approach in my answer, please check

Thank you for your prompt response. I am unable to see the attached screenshots . I can see "Enter Image description here" instead of image.

@RaviRanjan Try to check your network connectivity.

@RaviRanjan can you check here

@RaviRanjan did it work for you?

I have not tried solution with your approach. We already have a logic app and we are trying to figure out the solution using existing design with the help of trigger condition. Thanks for your solution approach.
